# Does uninstalling the application removes the device owner settings the application has utilized?

Tags: android, adb, device-owner

I'm trying to create an application that can disable or hide other applications. After going through some online resources i found out that i have to make my application the device owner to do so.

I would like to know, if i make my application the device owner, will that permission be removed when i uninstall the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can't uninstall the device owner.  You also can't become the device owner if you're a Play Store app.  Device ownership really is only possible if its a device you physically own and can set up.

Comment: Then is there a way for me to hide apps or atleast prevent the user from opening other specific applications? [eg: if the user of my application selects a game application to be hidden/restricted my app should be able to hide/prevent users from opening the game application] Please let me know of a possible workaround for this. I need this for a demo.

Comment: Write a Launcher app.  That allows you to replace the home screen and app drawer.  That would enable you to not display the app in the app drawer.  It would not stop them from being able to go to settings->applications and seeing it there, or launching it from other places like the Play store.  Getting that deep would require device ownership or a custom OS.

Comment: Gabe, I made a launcher app and it worked! i could call the package manager and display only the applications i wanted. Thanks for the help!